# Bootstrap collapsible menu to open while hiding the opened div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 div which needs to be opened as and when clicked while hiding the previous opened div. How should I close the already opened `link 1` when I click on `link2` or `link 3`?

I want to open the tab which is clicked and close if there's any open div.

**Here's the code :**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1">
      Link 1
</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2">
      Link 2
</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3">
      Link 3
</a>


<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
     This is the description 1
</div> 
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
     This is the description 2
</div> 
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
     This is the description 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Woeking fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19505/)**.

Place your collapsed element inside a div then add `show.bs.collapse` event :

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">

  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1">
    Link 1
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2">
    Link 2
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3">
    Link 3
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
    This is the description 1
  </div> 
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
    This is the description 2
  </div> 
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
    This is the description 3
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: When the user clicks on Link 1 a second time, it disappears. Is there a way that one of the div remains open at all times? Else the page looks very empty. Thanks.